# Methods of breaking Chicken Boredom

Tags: chickens

I have 7 beautiful chickens, in the coop there is a place **for a mud bath and they have logs in the corner**, my hens and cockerel **only dogs and scraps when I do a bit of gardening (flip and crumble the dirt)** *but is there any other ways to break there boredom?* Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hang a cabbage from a piece of string!

Seriously - they *love* it - my mother's hens dance and bounce when they have cabbage-on-string to play with.

Here's [a random example on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoAIYuhYfik) – disclaimer: I don't know these hens! :)

Answer (score 0):

Chickens are social birds. Some farmers and animal scientists even say that even if you keep them in small cages the fact that they have "friends" makes them "happy" - not necessary my opinion.

For your question: Feed them from the ground. Plant some plants if you can. Create heights and shelter areas. Differ their food on a regular basis, i.e. feed safe leafy vegetables. You can even chase them around or spray them from time to time if they don't go crazy.

Comment: I can't put some plants down as they like to eat the seeds, they have a shelter underneath the cage and thank you for the rest idea's I appreciate them, I have learnt that my oldest loves meal-worms (but she won't let other hens or the cockerel to have some too)